# math.max and math.min in a user defined function

Tags: javascript

Beginner here. I have been trying to get math.max work inside a user defined function but can't seem to get it to work. The function is supposed to take two numbers from two text boxes and display the larger of the two in a third text box. The rest of my code works fine but I can't get this to work and I am not sure what to do.

```
function Maximum()
    // Assumes: first and second are any two numbers taken input from a Textbox
    // Results: Displays the maximum of the two input numbers in the outputDiv
    {
        var first=parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
        var second=parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
        maximum = math.max(first, second);
        document.getElementById('outputDiv').value = maximum;       
    }
```

Comment: is outputDiv a div?? if so, you should use document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML= maximum;

Comment: Add `var` in front of `maximum`

Comment: var only strictly needed in strict mode (Edit: good practice, though)

Comment: They should be using strict mode anyway. Better to teach good practice than to nitpick over the validity of bad code.

Comment: Learn to [use your console.](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log) If you check there, it will alert you that `math` is `undefined`. From there, you might be able to figure out that you spelled it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capitalize "math":

```
Math.max(first, second);
```

Also, you need to replace `.value` to `.innerText` or `.innerHTML` when trying to display text.

Answer (score 1):

It is because math has to be capital

[image]